# AWS SSL security error : [curl] 60: SSL certificate prob...: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: php, curl, ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to connect Amazon's S3 files from my (localhost) Windows 8 machine running `AppServ 2.5.10` (which includes `Apache 2.2.8`, `php 5.2.6`, `mysql 5.0.51b` and `phpMyAdmin 2.10.3`) using `Amazon SDK` for php.

In order to be compatible with `Amazon SDK's` namespace feature, I replaced php with version `5.3.28` by downloading its zipped file and unzipped it.

My php code works fine to access `S3` file in `Amazon EC2` but it failed in my Windows local host.

However when I run the php srcipt to read `Amazon S3` bucket file in Windows local host machine, I got SSL error as following:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Guzzle\Http\Exception\CurlException'
>   with message '[curl] 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local
>   issuer certificate [url]
>   https://images-st.s3.amazonaws.com/us/123977_sale_red_car.png' in
>   C:\AppServ\www\ecity\vendor\guzzle\guzzle\src\Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti.php:342
>   Stack trace:
>
> #0
>   C:\AppServ\www\ecity\vendor\guzzle\guzzle\src\Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti.php(283):
>   Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti->isCurlException(Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\Request),
>   Object(Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlHandle), Array)
>
> #1
>   C:\AppServ\www\ecity\vendor\guzzle\guzzle\src\Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti.php(248):
>   Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti->processResponse(Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\Request),
>   Object(Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlHandle), Array)
>
> #2
>   C:\AppServ\www\ecity\vendor\guzzle\guzzle\src\Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti.php(231):
>   Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti->processMessages()
>
> #3
>   C:\AppServ\www\ecity\vendor\guzzle\guzzle\src\Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti.php(215):
>   Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti->executeHandles()
>
> #4
>   C:\AppServ\www\ecity\ven in
>   C:\AppServ\www\ecity\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\Aws\Common\Client\AbstractClient.php
>   on line 288

I download the certifate from http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and  define it in php.ini as following:

```
curl.cainfo = "C:\AppServ\cacert.pem"
```

but I still got the same error. It seems php doesn't honor the `curl.cainfo` defined in `php.ini`.

My php version is `5.3.28` according to `localhost/phpinfo.php`.

I also checked the `cainfo` parameter to be correct as `C:\AppServ\cacert.pem`  using

```
echo ini_get( "curl.cainfo" ) ;
```

in the php script.

Php version higher than `5.3` shall support `curl.cainfo` in `php.ini`.

In Windows' command line, I check curl behavior and it seems work fine.

```
C:\Users\Jordan>curl  https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/images-st/aaa.txt
   curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
   ......

C:\Users\Jordan>curl --cacert C:\AppServ\cacert.crt  https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/images-st/aaa.txt
  This is aaa.txt file.
  Stored in Amazon S3 bucket.
```

Is it because I used Apache in Windows which doesn't match php `5.3.28` zip file I downloaded from http://windows.php.net/download/ VC9 x86 Thread Safe (2014-Jun-11 01:09:56) zip version.

In my apache's  httpd-ssl.conf file, I have the following setting even I use from local host in Windows 8.

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>

DocumentRoot "C:/AppServ/www"
ServerName localhost:443
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost.com
ErrorLog "C:/AppServ/Apache2.2/logs/error.log"
TransferLog "C:/AppServ/Apache2.2/logs/access.log"

SSLEngine on

SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
SSLCertificateFile "C:/AppServ/Apache2.2/conf/mydomain.cert"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/AppServ/Apache2.2/conf/mydomain.key"

<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory "C:/Apache2.2/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" \
     nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
     downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

CustomLog "C:/AppServ/Apache2.2/logs/ssl_request.log" \
      "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>
```

Now I am wondering what is the problem and how to connect to `Amazon S3` bucket files and `RDS` database without producing these `curl` cannot get local issuer certificate problems from my Windows 8 local host.

Any advice?

Comment: Have you tried [setting the `ssl.certificate_authority` option](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/faq.html#what-do-i-do-about-a-curl-ssl-certificate-error) when you instantiate the SDK?

Comment: Thanks! Jeremy. You AWS expert did catch the problem right away.

Comment: for me it worked what @user2818066 mentioned: downloading the certifate from http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and defining it in php.ini as following: curl.cainfo = "C:\AppServ\cacert.pem"

Comment: Make sure you download the cacert.pem from the correct place: https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html

Answer (score 46):

As mentioned by [Jeremy Lindblom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1178974/jeremy-lindblom) in the comments, the solution for **AWS SDK v2** is to set the `ssl.certificate_authority` option when instantiating the SDK:

```php
$aws = Aws\Common\Aws::factory(array(
    'region' => 'us-west-2',
    'ssl.certificate_authority' => '/path/to/updated/cacert.pem'
));
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/faq.html#what-do-i-do-about-a-curl-ssl-certificate-error

---

I'll add that this was changed in the **AWS SDK v3**, here is the new method:

```php
$client = new DynamoDbClient([
    'region'  => 'us-west-2',
    'version' => 'latest',
    'http'    => [
        'verify' => '/path/to/my/cert.pem'
    ]
]);
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/guide/configuration.html#verify

Comment: Also you can set the verify to false, for the purpose of testing.

`$client = new DynamoDbClient([
    'region'  => 'us-west-2',
    'version' => 'latest',
    'http'    => [
        'verify' => false
    ]
]);`

Answer (score 27):

For those using WampServer, open the `php.ini` file then scroll down to the bottom and add the following:

`curl.cainfo = "C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.2.3\cacert.pem"`

Make sure you have the `cacert.pem` file in the folder of the current php version you are using. In my case, I have it in the `php7.2.3` folder.

Comment: If you can not find it ( as it was in my case ), you can download it from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

Answer (score 8):

I was getting the same error If you want to use http then you can use below solution:

```
 Error executing "PutObject" on "https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/mybucketname/TestBanner1_e1d8d74e41"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

I have resolved it by using http method this is not secure to use secure way enter _ curl.cainfo = "/path/to/file.cacert.pem"_ in php.ini file :

**Solution**:

```
'options' => [
'scheme' => 'http',
],
```

**Complete Example code:**

```
 // ...
's3bucket' => [
'class' => \frostealth\yii2\aws\s3\Storage::className(),
'region' => 'ap-southeast-2',
'credentials' => [ // Aws\Credentials\CredentialsInterface|array|callable
'key' => 'JGUTEHCDE.............OSHS',
'secret' => 'SJEUC-----------jzy1-----rrT',
],
'bucket' => 'yours3bucket',
//'cdnHostname' => 'http://example.cloudfront.net',
'defaultAcl' => \frostealth\yii2\aws\s3\Storage::ACL_PUBLIC_READ,
'debug' => false, // bool|array
'options' => [
'scheme' => 'http',
],

],
// ...
```

Comment: This works but just to mention it's the same as disabling SSL through `verify = false`.

Comment: Yes If you want to use http then you can use just for testing.

Answer (score 7):

```
$s3 = new S3Client
         ([
            'version' => 'latest',
            'scheme' =>'http',
            'region'  => $this->config->item('s3_region'),
            'credentials' => [
                'key'    => $this->config->item('s3_access_key'),
                'secret' => $this->config->item('s3_secret_key')
            ],
        ]);
```

add Scheme to http if your protocol is Http

Answer (score 7):

I have faced the same issue but after research, I have found a Laravel native solution for the AWS S3 bucket.

**Step 1:** Go to the `config/filesystems.php`

**Step 2:** Add the `'scheme'  => 'http'` in **'s3'** array, like below:

```
's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
            'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false,
            'scheme'  => 'http'
        ],
```

That's it. Now, you can run your app and test it.

Once you move your web app on the live server and if your web app runs over the ***https*** protocol then you need to remove this attribute

Comment: Simple and straight forward. Thank you Mayank