# Having trouble authenticating in Drush with SSL

Tags: windows, curl, drush, pantheon

My Drupal site is hosted at Pantheon (getpantheon.com), I'm using Drush on a Windows 7 x64 machine. I was reading this article on commands using Drush + Terminus (a special Drush extension for Pantheon sites):

https://www.getpantheon.com/blog/five-steps-feeling-drush

I want to be able to use both Drush and Terminus to quickly and efficiently manage my Pantheon Drupal sites.

I installed Terminus fine and was able to issue all the drush-related commands and connect to the server. However, when I got to the part about using 'pauth' to authenticate and use the actual Terminus commands my authentication was successful but then on the part where it's supposed to say 'Success!' :) It says instead:

> Dashboard unavailable: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Pantheon told me:

> This is due to Windows not bundling an Internet-friendly set of Certificate Authority (CA) certs with curl. Check Stack Overflow or the like for a bunch of solutions

Any suggestions on how to proceed? I'm not familiar with cURL at all, so something basic would be great, thanks.

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it using this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24620393/aws-ssl-security-error-curl-60-ssl-certificate-prob-unable-to-get-local

Answer (score 0):

Still new here...figuring this out. I should have done more research :p I found the answer here:

[AWS SSL security error : [curl] 60: SSL certificate prob...: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24620393/aws-ssl-security-error-curl-60-ssl-certificate-prob-unable-to-get-local)

Once I'd downloaded the .pem file and saved it in a directory and referenced it from php.ini I was good to go.