# AWS EC2 PHP SDK SSL error

Tags: php, ssl, curl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Im trying to set an auto start and stop on my EC2 using PHP script. When im trying to run the script it turns out error like below,

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Guzzle\Http\Exception\CurlException'
>   with message '[curl] 60: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA
>   cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed [url]
>   https://ec2.ap-southeast-1a.amazonaws.com/' .... ....

i've reinstalled the ca-certificates in my centos server. but the error persist.

Below are the specification details,
PHP5.3.
aws php sdk 2.8
centos 6.5

Anyone encounter this error before?

Comment: Looks a lot like this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24620393/aws-ssl-security-error-curl-60-ssl-certificate-prob-unable-to-get-local?rq=1 ... But the unfortunate thing is the answer doesn't seem to work with AWS PHP SDK v3

Comment: The solution seem working for AWS PHP SDK v3. But it turns out to another issue.

Comment: Well, it looks like the solution pointed to (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/faq.html#what-do-i-do-about-a-curl-ssl-certificate-error) tries to use Aws/Common/Aws which is not available in SDK v3.