# Unable to add XML Dom to AWS S3 bucket

Tags: php, xml, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to generate an xml on the fly using XMLDocument and add to a folder in the AWS S3 bucket

```html
public static function putXML_To_Bucket($bucket, $dom, $location) {
  $rest = new S3Request('PUT', $bucket, $location);
  $rest->data = $dom->saveXML();
  $rest->size = strlen($rest->data);
  $rest->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');   
  $rest = $rest->getResponse();
  var_dump($rest);
    
  if ($rest->error === false && $rest->code !== 200)
   $rest->error = array('code' => $rest->code, 'message' => 'Unexpected HTTP status');
  if ($rest->error !== false) {
   trigger_error(sprintf("S3::putBucket({$bucket}, {$acl}, {$location}): [%s] %s",
   $rest->error['code'], $rest->error['message']), E_USER_WARNING);
   return false;
  }
  return true;
 }
```

The var_dump($rest) produces this error

```html
object(stdClass)#9 (1) {
  ["error"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["code"]=>
    int(60)
    ["message"]=>
    string(63) "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"
    ["resource"]=>
    string(34) "/mybucket/"
  }
}
```

Note I am developing from localhost.

I don't have a clue why this is happening. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this link will help:  `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24620393/aws-ssl-security-error-curl-60-ssl-certificate-prob-unable-to-get-local`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

J.Garth's note helped me solve the issue. 
Thanks

[Stackoverflow suggestion by J Garth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24620393/aws-ssl-securit%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8By-error-curl-60-ssl-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcertificate-prob-una%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bble-to-get-local)